# Counting the number of spaces in C program

Tags: c

Lowercase and uppercase letters, special characters and numbers are working just fine.
The program can't count total characters and spaces properly.
What should I add to make this work? Appreciate your help!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include<conio.h>

main(){
char cMessage[100];
int  cChar,cLow=0, cUp=0, cSpec=0, cSpace=0, cNum=0;

printf("Enter your message: ");
scanf("%s", cMessage);

int x=0;
while(x<strlen(cMessage)){

printf("%c",cMessage[x]);
cChar++;

if(islower(cMessage[x])){ cLow++;}

else if(isupper(cMessage[x])){ cUp++;}

else if(cMessage[x] == ' '){ cSpace++; }

else if(isdigit(cMessage[x])){ cNum++; }

else{ cSpec++;
}
x++;
}
printf("\nTotal Characters: %d", cChar);
printf("\nTotal Lowercase Letters: %d", cLow);
printf("\nTotal Uppercase Letters: %d", cUp);
printf("\nTotal Special Characters: %d", cSpec);
printf("\nTotal Spaces: %d", cSpace);
printf("\nTotal Numbers: %d", cNum);
getch();



}
```

Comment: `main()` is archaic. Declare it as `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the input/format specifiers: '%s' or '%[...]' always include a MAX FIELD WIDTH modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those items always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Comment: for ease if readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after EVERY opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces  note: treat the closing brace '}}' as a separate statement. 2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  3) separate code blocks ( `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The program can't count total characters and spaces properly ?*  One reason is that the statement `scanf("%s", cMessage);` won't read the white spaces or read upto *space* only. If you want to read the `cMessage` with whitespace then use `fgets()`.

```
fgets(cMessage,sizeof(cMessage),stdin);/* use fgets() instead of scanf() */
```

Or you can use `scanf()` like this

```
scanf("%[^\n]", cMessage);/* it read the whitespaces also */
```

Read the manual page of `fgets()` here https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets